# How to use 'remap' in reclassify tool code in ArcGIS Python Toolbox

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-toolbox

I am making a reclassify tool in ArcGIS python toolbox (.pyt) ...
I am able to use the remap datatype but am not able to parse the information present in Remap in the Reclassify function's third argument ...

Code is below:

```
import arcpy, string
import numpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

class Toolbox(object):
def __init__(self):
    """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
    .pyt file)."""
    self.label = "Toolbox"
    self.alias = ""

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [Remap]

class Remap(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.label = "Remap"
    self.description = ""
    self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    feature_class = arcpy.Parameter( displayName="Input Raster ", name="input1", datatype="Raster Layer", parameterType="Required", direction="Input") 
    field = arcpy.Parameter( displayName="Input Field ", name="input2", datatype="Field", parameterType="Required", direction="Input") 
    remap = arcpy.Parameter( displayName="ReMap ", name="remap", datatype="remap", parameterType="Required", direction="Input")     
    out_class = arcpy.Parameter( displayName="Output Raster ", name="ouput1", datatype="Raster Layer", parameterType="Required", direction="Output") 

    field.value = "Value"  
    field.enabled = True

    remap.parameterDependencies = [feature_class.name,field.name]

    params = [feature_class,field,remap,out_class]
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    return True
def updateParameters(self, parameters):

    #if parameters[0].value:
        #parameters[1].parameterDependencies = [parameters[0].name]
        #parameters[2].parameterDependencies = [parameters[0].name,parameters[1].name]
    return 

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    inRaster = parameters[0]
    outRaster = parameters[3]
    remap2 = parameters[2]
    arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(inRaster,"Value",remap2,outRaster,"DATA")
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

2 remarks about your code:
- your list of parameters is called 'params' initially then you refer to it as 'parameters'.
- replace 'arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa' with 'Reclassify'.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a bit buggy (remap values don't populate automatically), but I managed to get something working (10.7.1) based on your original code and some help from the ESRI forum.

In order to activate the "Classify" button, which is initially grayed out, click on one of the other buttons... "Reverse New Values" or "Precision..." and that should activate the "Classify..." button.  You can then choose the classification method you want and the no. of classes.

```
import arcpy, string
import numpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Remap]

class Remap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Remap"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        inputraster = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Raster ",
            name="input1",
            datatype="Raster Layer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input") 

        field = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Field ",
            name="input2",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        field.value = "Value"  
        field.enabled = True

        remap = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="ReMap ",
            name="remap",
            datatype="GPSARemap",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        remap.parameterDependencies = [inputraster.name,field.name]

        outputraster = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output Raster ",
            name="ouput1",
            datatype="Raster Layer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output") 


        params = [inputraster,field,remap,outputraster]
        return params

    def initializeParameters(self):
        """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters called when the tool is opened."""
        self.params[2].parameterDependencies = [0]
        return

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True
    def updateParameters(self, parameters):

##        if parameters[0].value:            
##            parameters[2].parameterDependencies = [parameters[0].name,parameters[1].name]

        return 

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        inRaster = parameters[0].valueAsText
        field = parameters[1].valueAsText
        outRaster = parameters[3].valueAsText
        remap2 = parameters[2].valueAsText

        messages.addWarningMessage(str(remap2))

        outputraster = Reclassify(inRaster, field, remap2, "NODATA")
        outputraster.save(outRaster)
        return
```